# Can I rig a model and have the bones not be connected?

Tags: modeling, rigging, rigify, pose-mode, rigidbody

This is my first time creating a model like this, would rigging the model with the bones like this even work? Also if it did, how could I mirror the left foot to the right foot so its exact? Symmetrize doesn't work.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes you don't have to connect the bones (and you can still parent to the spine with the *Keep Offset* option). As for *Symmetrize*, the bones you want to symmetrize need to have a suffixe like ".R" or "_R", for example *Leg.R*, otherwise nothing will happen. To symmetrize, switch your armature to *Edit* mode, select all and header menu > *Armature > Symmetrize*:

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to just copy paste and mirror the bone to the other foot?

Comment: To symmetrize, switch your armature to *Edit* mode, select all and header menu > *Armature > Symmetrize*. Is it your question?